# startx and boot aren't working

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, nvidia, manjaro, startx

When i try to boot or startx, it fails, but some time ago everything was alright.

Here is my log file:
https://dpaste.com/8XBNQAVNE

Here is my xorg.conf:
https://dpaste.com/CUGU3BESJ

I'm using nvidia 1060GTX. All nvidia drivers are installed. Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: The links are dead, there is no info to go on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by installing linux59-nvidia.

Comment: The question said "all nvidia drivers are installed"...